# A C# project runs on ssl from VS, but fails with docker-compose with ssl problem

Tags: c#, ssl

What can be the problem? This exception is throwned by the console while running with docker (docker-compose). The VS2022 runs the project perfectly.

> Unhandled exception. System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to
> configure HTTPS endpoint. No server certificate was specified, and the
> default developer certificate could not be found or is out of date.

I have run : `dotnet dev-certs https --clean`  AND `dotnet dev-certs https --trust`

Answer (score 0):

You are not creating the dev certificate. You can do that with:

```
dotnet dev-certs https -ep $env:USERPROFILE\.aspnet\https\aspnetapp.pfx -p crypticpassword
dotnet dev-certs https --trust
```

[See here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/additional-tools/self-signed-certificates-guide#create-a-self-signed-certificate) for reference

Comment: Also note that the certificate name, in this case aspnetapp.pfx must match the project assembly name. crypticpassword is used as a stand-in for a password of your own choosing.